# how to set the column width to fit the width of content in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

from the fiddle below, i am trying to reduce the width of the bootstrap column that contains the image, .how can i set the column that fits the size of the content i.e., the image.

https://jsfiddle.net/thf3uy2v/

```
<div class = "row">

<div class = "col-md-2">
<div><a href = ""><img class = "image-responsive" src = "http://www.leapcms.com/images/100pixels1.gif"></a></div>
</div>

<div class = "col-md-10">
<div>ssssssssssssssssssssssss</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution to your request:
In CSS:

```
.image-responsive{
    max-width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To your css, if you know the size of the img you could do this, although might not be the best approach(if img size's are arbitrary). But if this is for a one time use case could definitely work.

```
.col-md-2 {
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 100px;
 padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: can a custom class be added to override the bootstrap class, say i want to override the above

Comment: @Deep13 of course you can, or you can add a custom class to do without touching the provided bootstrap class. Keep in mind if your class is being overridden then just be more specific with the drilling down in your css file. For example .container .row .example class or .container .row div.example class. If all else use of the "!important" after the style should be used sparingly. Hope this helps.